# SwifUI onTapGesture inside ScollView not alway detect tap

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have problem with Views that have `onTapGesture` and are placed inside ScollView
This onTapGesture is not always reacting to tap gesture.
I need to tap precisely on such view.
It seems like there is conflict with ScrollView drag?

I've tried

```
highPriorityGesture 
onTapGesture
gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance:0).onChange { })
gesture(TapGesture().onEnded { })
```

Views have contentShape(Rectangle()) added to them

It somtimes works ok sometimes doesn't. On simulature it most of the time works ok, on physical device it is much worse.

```
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< elements.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text(elements[i])
                            .fixedSize()
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    selectedElement = i
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the behavior that you describe with that example code, but maybe you could try the following modifier in case another gesture is operating at the same time:

```
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({
              selectedElement = 1
            }))
```